# How do I add custom fields to a wiki page?

Tags: wiki, column

I create a new wiki pages library (on SharePoint Foundation 2010) and create some new custom fields (1 choice and 1 text). When I create a new Wiki Page these custom fields are not shown on the web interface. I have to go on the ribbon and choose Edit Properties to see them.

Is there any way to show these custom fields on the page during editing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for regular (not Enterprise) wiki pages. It involves adding ListFieldIterator control to the wiki page template (wkpstd.aspx) which will be in charge  of listing all custom fields below the main content and then creating a new rendering template for the ListFieldIterator control for displaying those fields on the page.

Details can be found here:
http://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/adding-custom-fields-to-wiki-pages/

Comment: Please, do not just link to your blog to drive traffic. Write an abstract of the post here, and if people do like what you are saying, they will find your blog anyway :)

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. [mod]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to customize the page layout used by that wiki site -but I am not an expert on that topic.

Another way of editing these metadata is going to the site library where the wiki pages are stored and then adding you custom fields to the current view. But of course that pretty far away from that what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post to do exactly what you describe. You can find that post right [here](http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-custom-fields-editor-control-in-page-edit-mode/).

Be sure to note that my post adds the controls only to a publishing page of a certain content type. You can remove the check for the Publishing page and it should work well for you.