# Customize Form (new wiki page)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, library, wiki-pages

Firstly, I would like to create a section for news in SharePoint, for this I use a wiki library, so far, it's good. Everything works fine, but I'd like to change is some point for my needs.

when a new article is create (ie, a new wiki page) I have only the Name field, which will be used as the name and url at the same time, or, I would like to add a title and description field which will shall defer the uRL of the page to avoid (20%) in the url.

The problem is that in SharePoint Designer I can not edited form (new wiki page)?

a solution to customize the form to add a new wiki page?, so that I can make available custom fields to capture the gold creation. And must go through Visual Studio?.

with images :

When I add a new wiki page, I have a form like this:

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=8722552201.png

but I would like to propose a shape similar to that of editing, when you add a new page :

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=9919531302.png

Thank you for your help, and I apologize in advance for my English.

Platform: SharePoint 2010 / Visual Studio 2010 / SharePoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

That dialog cannot be changed for an individual library. It's the default new page dialog for the whole site collection. You would need to write code to change that. Out of the box, just create the page, then click the Page ribbon and use the "Edit Properties" command to set the required fields.

In [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-to-a-wiki-page) a code solution is linked, but it applies to publishing pages, not wiki pages and I don't know if it works for wiki pages as well.

You may want to consider a publishing library instead of a wiki library. When you edit the pages in a publishing library, you will see a view of metadata fields as defined in the page layout. You can create page layouts to suit your needs and can make sure that metadata fields show prominently when a page is edited.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just look around, but I think it is not the solution to my problem.

I just added more information to the problem (need)

Comment: I've edited my answer.